# old java embedded mobile phone application development using Java ME

Tags: java, java-me

for some hobby project I need to develop some J2ME application for my old Nokia 2690. but I couldn't find any platform to do that. it appears recent J2ME tools which come's with netbeans is dedicated for raspberry pi or other MCU development. or may be I couldn't find the way of mobile development... so any suggestion would be really appreciated... thanks in advance

Comment: You might need a Series 40 v2 SDK or something from Nokia to develop apps for it. Its rather legacy, I have no idea whether its possible to download something like that any more. Maybe it doesn't even work on newer operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is Perfect For J2ME Mobile App development. Last One Year Ago I developed a simple j2me app in netbeans 8 . Here is a guide for you. https://netbeans.org/kb/73/javame/quickstart.html .